# Search a string inside a spooled text file in BAT file

Tags: sql, database, batch-file, cmd, scheduler

I am a complete beginner in bat files. I am explaining the scenario of mine requirement. Hope I will get the exact o/p from you gurus.

This is my current batch file:
 **Note : *findstr* command specified by OP in comment included in code but spacing - well, who knows? OP to edit, please**

```
CALL %ORACLE_HOME%/bin/sqlplus "/as sysdba" @D:\Long_Running\Long_running_job.sql > D:\Long_Running\LongrunningJobs.txt 

  call :CheckEmpty "%file%"
          powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File D:\Long_Running\Send_email_report.ps1
          goto :eof

         :CheckEmpty
       if %~z1 == 0 exit
```

This basically connects SQL plus, connects as sysdba, go to location where Long_running.sql file is present and spools the o/p to LongrunningJobs.txt.
From there it triggers mails in the next line(power shell).

Requirement: If I can search for a particular string say "ABCDE" in the LongrunningJobs.txt file and if it matches then it should  trigger the mail else it should not trigger mail and simply come out.
What exactly should I input? I used FINDSTR might be I didn't use it correctly, it did not go well. The mail was not triggered.

Comment: So the string you want to search for is located in a text file?

Comment: Yes . the query result goes straight to text file.

Comment: No, I mean the search text, you said "ABCDE from a .txt file". Does this mean that "ABCDE", i.e. the search text, is contained in a separate .txt file? This would then have to be read in first.

Comment: yes. the string "ABCDE" should be searched from this LongrunningJobs.txt  file. I did not save this string(ABCDE)  anywhere till now. what i meant is like, suppose this .txt files has data as ("gopal", "amit", "ABCDE"). then it should go to the powershell line, else come out. if the content of LongrunningJobs.txt doesnot have this particular text i.e. "ABCDE" it should come out and donot trigger an email.

Comment: findstr /c:"ABCDE"  D:\Long_Running\LongrunningJobs.txt && (

           call :CheckEmpty "%file%"
              powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File D:\Long_Running\Send_email_report.ps1
              goto :eof

             :CheckEmpty
           if %~z1 == 0 exit

 ) || ( 

            :CheckEmpty
           if %~z1 == 0 exit 
)  This I tried , but did not work.

Comment: I've included the `findstr` code into your question but I've no idea about the **actual** format you've used - why is why you should have included the `findstr` with which you had trouble in your original post rather than leaving us to guess. Please check and edit if necessary.

Comment: @MAgoo .. The findstr was used by me as I mentioned earlier to check, whether it meets my requirements or not. but it did not work. The code I mentioned in question, previously is the one, which simply sends a mail, watever data is present in the Longrunningjobs.txt file irrespective of any thing. i gave explanation for that one in my post. No issues. I ll try your solution still, if it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\LongrunningJobs.txt"

:: first test : empty file
COPY /y NUL "%outfile%" >NUL 2>NUL
ECHO test 1
FINDSTR "ABCDE" "%outfile%" >NUL &&ECHO Send mail

:: second test : file NOT containing "ABCDE"
ECHO something >"%outfile%"
ECHO test 2
FINDSTR "ABCDE" "%outfile%" >NUL &&ECHO Send mail

:: third test : file containing "ABCDE"
ECHO ABCDE>>"%outfile%"
ECHO test 3
FINDSTR "ABCDE" "%outfile%" >NUL &&ECHO Send mail

GOTO :EOF
```

I use `destdir` to keep from cluttering my system.

Note that `send mail` will *only* be echoed in the third case, where the subject file contains the target string.

Comment: This works fine if tested in local machine. concept is correct. I am getting an ECHO to the correct one. But that did not work for the above. Its not Calling the mail which I expect. I am not sure why. still debugging. though your solution is correct in some case.

Answer (score 0):

```
          FINDSTR "ABCDE" "%file%" >NUL && (
          powershell -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File D:\Long_Running\Send_email_report.ps1
          goto :eof )
```

@Magoo has given the correct answer, I was calling the function which i should not have. Thanks a lot everyone.